# Particle System not working on Play()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a particle effect that I would like to trigger to play, and then stop. I'm sure this is an easy fix that I am over looking.

The particle can instantiate and play, but this obviously leaves overhead and particles that are active in the hierarchy when they don't need to be.

```
public void EmitFX(ParticleSystem particle)
{
   Instantiate(particle, particlePos, Qauternion.identity)
}
```

I would like to use methods within ParticleSystem but am running into some problems. I have been using the manual and am still running into a block. I've googled this up and down, based on problems others had I changed my code to the following. It still does not work and is now a monster based on hacks other people found useful :/

```
public void EmitFX(ParticleSystem particle)
    {
        particle = particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        particle.transform.position = ballPos;

        var em = particle.emission;
        em.enabled = true;       

        particle.Play();
    }
```

Here is a s/c of a particle in the Inspector.

[image]

Comment: Your title says you have trouble playing and your question says you can instantiate and play, can you please clarify what your question is? Additionally, what are these "problems" and "blocks" you are running into?

Comment: The particle can instantiate and play, but this obviously leaves overhead and particles that are active in the hierarchy when they don't need to be.

I would like to instantiate the particle system once. Then be able to Play() it and Stop() playing when needed. The problems and blocks are that regardless of what I change or try code wise I cannot get it to work. I have read the manual and cannot get the Play() function within ParticleSystem to run as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, not sure what the `particle = particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();` line is supposed to do? The `particle` variable is the **ParticleSystem** provide to your `EmitFX()` method so no need to call for this.

My guess is you have some references problems in your script (some variables referring to your prefab, then what you instantiate overrides this reference, ...) so I wrote you a "cleaner" version of your code (by merging your two scripts):

```
#region Attributes
[SerializeField]
private ParticleSystem particle;

private ParticleSystem generatedParticle;
#endregion

#region MonoBehaviour
protected void Start()
{
    generatedParticle = null;
}

protected void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        EmitFX(particle);
    }
}
#endregion

public void EmitFX(ParticleSystem a_Particle)
{
    if(generatedParticle == null)
    {
        generatedParticle = Instantiate(particle, particlePos, Qauternion.identity);
    }

    generatedParticle.transform.position = ballPos;       
    generatedParticle.Play();

    // You can set a fixed duration here if your particle system is looping
    // (I assumed it was not so I used the duration of the particle system to detect the end of it)
    StartCoroutine(StopFXAfterDelay(generatedParticle.main.duration));
}

private IEnumerator StopFXAfterDelay(float a_Delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(a_Delay);
    generatedParticle.Stop();
}
```

What it does is it store the instantiated particle in a variable so it can access it later and remember it has been generated. Also I added a coroutine to deactivate it at the end of the effect.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: not sure what the particle = particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>(); line is supposed to do? At that point I had read so many 'tips' people had used to get it to function I figured why not throw it all in there but agree that line is just bad and wrong. I appreciate you taking the time out to help me. Unfortunately this isn't working for me either.

EDIT-    It works if the line If check is if(generatedParticle == null).

Thanks a ton.

Comment: My bad on it still having this old bad habit of calling `if(someObject)` instead of `if(someObject != null)` : this is caused by the way Unity overrides Object class I think. However I should dig this deeper :) Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I am going to place here what worked for me since the problem persists in the later versions of Unity.

Instead of just calling: `particle.Play()` first stop the particle system like the code below.

```
particles.Stop();
if (particles.isStopped)
{
     particles.Play();
}
```

Where 'particles' is a component of type "ParticleSystem".